# How do you do your performance check when you make some edits in github

Tags: git, open-source

I am new to Git and Git Hub. I have made some edits in some GitHub repos and want to check relative performance in terms of time with the default Git repository. What is the best way to go about doing this?

One way I would go on is to create two git clones, one with the default one and the one in which I make my edits, and then run and compare them.

Any better way than this?

Answer (score 1):

I think the way that you are proposing sounds fine.  Just try to avoid making changes in both local repositories.

Another way would be to create a local branch in your local repo for your changes, and use `git checkout` to flip between the master branch and the branch containing your changes to run the performance tests for both.  But you can't switch branches if you have uncommitted changes.

Comment: The `git checkout` one seems promising. I will try that!

Answer (score 1):

Clone the default repository.

Create edits in a new branch or commit in the cloned repository.

Comparing the default and edited branches to measure performance .

You are able to make a new branch within the same clone for edits. This approach keeps the process to avoids the need for multiple clones. Use Git commands like `git clone`, `git branch`, and `git checkout` to this comparison.

Create branches as desired. For example: `git branch dev`. After that, you can switch branches using the following command: `git checkout dev`